# What font does Safe Host use for their logo?

Tags: logo, font-identification, typefaces

I want to identify this font in the [safehost.net](http://www.safehost.net/) logo. Can anyone assist please?

[image: safehost.net logo]

Comment: Try [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Comment: It was pretty useless for this one.

Comment: Tried it already...the results were very uplifting...nothing!!!

Comment: @Brendan thank you for making the image visible.

Comment: I couldn't find a good match for the font, but at least I found a bigger version of the logo where you can actually see the details; see above. (Tip for anyone else who ever needs to find a print-quality logo for an organization that doesn't provide a convenient visual identity kit online: try looking inside PDF files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WTF couldn't help, I'll try my obsessive eye.

## How about a modified version of [Russell Square](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/russell-square/)?

[image: Russell Square was most certainly the starting point]

Modifications are very simple with a purely geometric design like Russell.

1. Change the terminals on the `s`
2. Adjust the `t` a bit
3. Widen the characters across the board

Comment: No need to mock my answer, I was just giving my input :). That being said Russell Square is a much better fit.

Comment: Sorry, no mocking intended. Just commenting on the impatience of the asker ;)

Comment: @plainclothes My impatience comes from the fact that the cleint wants to see a design yesterday!!! Otherwise, I think your answer is better, and sorry Johannes, your attempt was good, but plainclothes' answer is much closer, so I have to change the accept to his.

Comment: Your rush is understood. Glad I could help.

Comment: No offense taken. Plainclothes' answer is much better suited and I'd prefer it to be the accepted answer. Best of luck on your project!

Comment: hmmmm ... that higher resolution image makes it clear that this may be more than a modded Russell. Using it as a base, however, I don't think extending some bezier handles from those hard corners would be too challenging.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of very similar square fonts, but I couldn't find any exact match either.

Using the larger logo I added above, WhatTheFont suggests [Gaudi ND](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/neufville/gaudi-nd/), which does match the general shape of the letters, but lacks the rounded feel and the distinctive line ends of the font in the logo:

[image: Gaudi ND]

A few other similar fonts I found include [Axion RX-14](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typeinnovations/axion-rx-14/), [Elevon Corp](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/daltonmaag/elevon-corp/) and [Paragraph](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/paragraph/paragraph/), but none of them really match those details either.

Also, after having stared at those pointy-round line tips for a while, I'm starting to feel more and more convinced that I've seen them before in some other logo.  But that might just be *déjà vu* kicking in.

**Edit:** Here are a few more fonts with a similar shape and line ends.  Still no exact match, though.

[Biome Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/biome-std/std-regular/):

[image: Biome Regular]

[Genos Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typesetit/genos/regular/):

[image: Genos Regular]

Comment: Ps. The small `www.safehost.net` text is [Eurostile Extended](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/eurostile/t-regular-extended/) or some clone of it.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have an exact match, I find that  a font that has a very similar feel, is [Lastwaerk](http://aajohan.deviantart.com/art/Lastwaerk-font-137804536) -- [Here is a preview of it, saying "safehost"](http://www.dafont.com/lastwaerk.font?text=safehost). It's free for both personal, and commercial use, so that's always a good thing.

Other than that I don't know any fonts off the top of my head that could be this font. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: Thank you. As you said, it isn't exact, but it is close enough for now. I have requested that they provide me with either the original font name or a vector of the logo, but until then, I just need something to do a mockup for them.

If anyone else has a closer match, I'd still appreciate it.